# Inductive sets are infinite

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, set-theory

I have an exercise that tells me to show that any inductive set is infinite (that is, equipotent with one of its subsets different from itself). I can imagine doing this with $\mathbb{N}$ taking the set of all even numbers and the function $f(n)=2n$, which is bijective, but I'm not sure how to show this for **any** inductive set.

A non-empty set $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ is inductive if for every $x\in A$ then $x+1\in A$

Comment: I assume that an inductive set is defined as nonempty as otherwise this is trivially false.

Comment: Yes, I think it should be non-empty; I edited the post to include that.

Comment: It might be easier to use the function $f(n) = n+1$, which should more easily generalize to arbitrary inductive sets

Comment: @kmam Sorry, I had to. Anyway, assuming that, the first function I can think of is as follows. Let $x_0\in A$ Now define $f:A\rightarrow A$ by, if $x\in x_0+\Bbb{N}$, $f(x)=x+2$, otherwise $f(x)=x+1$. From this $x_0+1\not \in f(A)$. I leave a formal proof of this to you.

Comment: @jacob The problem with that is if $A=\Bbb{Z}$ then $f(A)=A$

Comment: True there is more work to do; however I think my point stands

Comment: Is it necessary to use the definition directly?  It seems easier to find an injective map $f:\Bbb N \to A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be some inductive set. That is, for any $x\in X$, we have $x+1\in X$. Assume there is some "non-sum" element $y\in X$, where for no $y'\in X$ is $y$ equal to $y'+1$. Then $X\setminus\{y\}$ is a proper subset of $X$ which is equipotent with $X$.

Proving $X\setminus\{y\}$ can biject to $X$ isn't difficult, even if we don't assume the axiom of choice: let's say that $X'$ is a subset of $X$ that only consists of the members $y$, $y+1$, $y+1+1$, ..., or formally $X'$ is the closure of $\{y\}$ under the successor function. Then, let $f:X\setminus\{y\}\to X$ take $z\in X$ to $z+1$ if $z\in X'$, or $z$ otherwise. Because $z\in X'$ is either true or false (and successor is injective), we get that $f$ is an injection. For the other direction: since "predecessor" in $X'$ (taking $z+1\in X'$ to $z$) is unique, $f^{-1}:X\to X\setminus\{y\}$ is also an injection, so we've shown $X\setminus\{y\}$ and $X$ are equipotent.